# What is the intended use of this electrician's screwdriver?

Tags: identification, tools

I have this screwdriver with a "special" tip:

[image]

It happens to be a Klein 732 (the tip style is also conveniently marked on the handle):

[image]

Problem is, I've never found a screw that this will fit. Originally I thought it might fit the style of screw used on things like circuit breakers, switches, receptacles, etc. but none I've seen so far have fit. Many of them are a smaller size, but in addition they have a different profile like this:

[image]

So what is this likely to fit?

Comment: I've seen circuit breakers with that style of screw head. Similar to the ones you show, but the square socket rotated 45°.

Comment: My Google fu came up with this: https://toolguyd.com/milwaukee-ecx-screwdriver-bits/

Comment: [This video from Klein](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Tv5ef9pFAJM) shows the "combination tip" screwdriver in use.  I don't recognize the things it's used on.  Maybe you can and can write an answer based on the video.

Comment: @JRE interesting... I'm getting the impression that its not so much that certain applications use certain kinds of screws, but that there are just a wide variety of screws in the electrical domain and its not consistent which manufacturers use which ones for what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination screws are a very common type of screw that is allegedly compatible with either Phillips or flat blade screwdrivers. In my opinion, they are an abomination that work about equally poorly with both types of screwdriver. The blade in question is apparently designed to mitigate that abominable screw design. The YouTube video linked in the comment by JRE seems to less directly say what I just said.

The combination (or abomination) screws are very commonly used on products and sold separately in hardware stores.

Comment: Is the square + flathead example in the question then a different type of combination screw? (the screwdriver here is meant for a "diamond + flathead" screw?)

Comment: I believe the square + flathead is a different combination. There are screws that are designed for a square drive. The heads of ones that I have are small for the size of the screw. I suspect the square drive head allows more torque than other alternatives can accommodate in a small head. I doubt that the combination supports as much torque as either the flat head or square drive would support without being combined with the other. The "diamond' sort of fits the tip of a Phillips bit.